# Resetting / Managing User / NTFS Permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

I'm having a stressful time with User / File / NTFS permissions under Win8.1 I don't know when exactly it happend but something probably went a bit wrong with the permissions on some of my folders, especially my user folder.

It may be that some software I used in the past may have messed with it or it may be because I copy over certain files after each fresh install of my system, I don't know.

However something seems to wrong because I can't share anything from my user folder in the HomeGroup ("your folder couln't be shared) even though my User is the owner of each folder and has full permissions to it. There are some other users as well in the permissions tab (as well as some Unknown account S-1-5-21, but I figured that had to do with windows trying to share the files).

So is there a way (Tool, Guide, anything) that could help me resetting the permissions for certain folders to their "should be" state?

Also some good links on information about Windows Permissions would be great, something that tells me what use Users like the SYSTEM and TrustedInstaller have, what folder should have what permissions, who should be the owner etc. etc.

EDIT: I have / can set ownership of every folder and I figured that I can share everything (libraries, folders etc) EXCEPT my personal folders like Documents, Pictures etc. Is that normal? On my Laptop that doesn't work either..

Regards,
Xaser

Comment: First step you will have to take ownership of the folder but honestly if your permissions are incorrect your better off creating a new user profile

Comment: Should have mentioned that, I am the owner and have no problems moving permissions around (at least most of them). However something still seems to go very wrong when trying to share things etc.

Comment: If you can't take ownership of a folder that's not normally.

Comment: Can't you delete the homegroup and create a new one? Maybe that helps.